# How to get current category's image on template file in magento-1.9 on same category page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want add `.phtml` template file on category page only using `xml`.

I have  tried below code but note success.

```
 <catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" as="catalog_category_banner" name="catalog.category.banner" template="catalog/category/category-header.phtml"/>
    </reference>           
</catalog_category_default>
```

And in `header.phtml` file the below line.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog_category_banner'); ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" as="catalog_category_banner" name="catalog.category.banner" template="catalog/category/category-header.phtml"/>
    </reference>           
</default>

in header.phtml use $this->getChildHtml('catalog_category_banner');
```